# Check if two pandas dataframes are equal with mismatching indexes python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, similarity

I was wondering if it is possible to check the similarity between the two dataframes below. They are the same, however the first and the third rows are flipped. Is there a way to check that these dataframes are the same regardless of the order of the index? Thank you for any help!

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [merge](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) and then look for a subset of rows that doesn't exist in either dataframe.

```
df_a = pd.DataFrame([['a','b','c'], ['c','d','e'], ['e','f','g']], columns=['col1','col2','col3'])
df_b = pd.DataFrame([['e','f','g'], ['c','d','e'], ['a','b','c']], columns=['col1','col2','col3'])
df_merged = pd.merge(df_a, df_b, on=df_a.columns.tolist(), how='outer', indicator='Exist')
print(df_merged[(df_merged['Exist'] != 'both')])
```

Answer (score 0):

Sort the DFs in the same way and then compare, or iterate through all the columns, sort one column at a time and compare it

If this is ok and you need help writing the code, let me know